# What are my options for a search engine database on windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, sql-server-2008, lucene

I have a project to create a high traffic search engine similar to altavista.com. The windows .NET C# will be used for the project. I am looking for a good search engine database that can handle a very high load. I have taken a look at lucene and sql server 2008. I have read that lucene tends to get corrupt when the load is very high. So, I am considering sql server 2008 but I am uncertain sql server can handle a very high load over gigabytes of data.

The database will be given a chunk of data and needs to fetch similar data elsewhere in the table. it will act just the **similar questions** area on stackoverflow. It will need to search over millions of rows. Is sql server 2008 and lucene my only options

Comment: "I have read that lucene tends to get corrupt when the load is very high" - care to qualify that statement with a link or two?

Comment: BTW, millions of rows is not large...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Lucene sucessfully with high volume datas and i dint face data corruption problems.

But if you are worried about the standalone lucene, you can try [apache solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) instead, its a open-source search server based on the Lucene

> Solr is the popular, blazing fast open
>   source enterprise search platform from
>   the Apache Lucene project. Its major
>   features include powerful full-text
>   search, hit highlighting, faceted
>   search, dynamic clustering, database
>   integration, and rich document (e.g.,
>   Word, PDF) handling. Solr is highly
>   scalable, providing distributed search
>   and index replication, and it powers
>   the search and navigation features of
>   many of the world's largest internet
>   sites.

There is a .net client for solr in google code [solr.net](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/).. You can try this